# Pass multiple parameters in foreach loop but values not saving in DB

Tags: php

I am getting below values in Browser & I saved **AWBNoSeries** values in Database....

**ReturnMessage": "AWBNoSeries":["1234","5678",**

[image]

Now i need to save other 2 column values in mysql table **ecomexpress_awb** & in columns [ **awb_type** & **status** ].... When i tried below code, i dont get any error, but other 2 column values will not save in DB....

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","do_management4");
$parsedData = json_decode($curl_response, true);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ecomexpress_awb(awb,awb_type,status) VALUES (?,?,?)"); 

$cod="COD";
$status="unused";

//loop through values and insert each one into the db
foreach ($parsedData['AWBNoSeries'] as $awb){
    $stmt->bind_param("iii", $awb , $cod, $status);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close(); 
mysqli_close($mysqli); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bind you are saying that all the values are integers (`"iii"`)...

```
$stmt->bind_param("iii", $awb , $cod, $status);
```

I'm assuming you want strings....

```
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $awb , $cod, $status);
```

Comment: It's also worth checking for errors as this usually shows what is not working - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments

Comment: what we need to give for `datetime  - d` ?

Comment: Dates are passed as strings ( so `s`) Have a read through http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php which has some examples.